# How to use Scala/Akka Http to process more than one HTTP headers

Tags: scala, http-headers, akka-http

I am new to Scala and Akka Http.  Please excuse this newbie question.
I have the following code that handles incoming HTTP GET requests:

```
def  clickRoute():  Route = func1( requestData =>
  pathPrefix(“somewebevents”) {
    parameters(a, b) {
      ( my_a_var, my_b_var) =>
          optionalHeaderValueByName(“Referer”) { refHeaderOpt =>

               // process_logic
          }
    }
 }
```

The code does something within "process_logic" after it processes Referer HTTP header.  What I want to do is that it also processes another HTTP header “User-Agent”.
I almost want to chain the two together, grabbing both Referer and User-Agent.

I have been playing with the syntax and cannot quite find a way where I can pick up more than one HTTP headers and then proceed with “process_logic”.

Any tip much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using the default directives you could use `extractRequest`:

```
extractRequest { request =>
  val headers: Seq[HttpHeader] = request.headers
  // fetch the headers you need for processing
}
```

If you need to do this often implement a custom directive is also an option.

Comment: Why the headers are Seq and not Map?